# Dynamically referencing to header and footer in all PHP pages within different directories and sub-directories

Tags: php, html, content-management-system

**UPDATE 1:** to have a clear view of what is happening, you can [download a snippet of the script from here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jygzy85ruj3dvh6/sitename.rar?dl=0)

I am working in a new website that has the same `header`, `footer` in all PHP pages.

In the header I am referencing to other common files in website that like `.css`, `.js`, `functions`, `classes`, `db connection`, and etc.

for instance, the `default.css` is in `/common/stylesheets/`

and my header.php and footer.php are in `/common/html/` folder

so my header.php file is something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>The Header</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="common/stylesheets/default.css">
</head>
<body>
```

In my website `index.php` I included the header `<?php include('common/html/header.php'); ?>` and this is working fine... BUT the problems appear when I include the header in other php pages within other directories or sub directories e.g. `/pages/admin/dashboard.php`, everything messed up and that page no more linked to the `default.css` file.

**So, what I am looking for is a method or logic where I reference to these common files and folders in every PHP page no matter its location; e.g. site root, a directory in the site root, or a sub-directory... etc...**

here is an image of my website root

[image: sample website root]

***Your help is highly appreciated...***

*P.S. I've tried to use some superglobals variables such as `$_SERVER['']` in `config.inc.php` file  to define the paths, then I included that file in the `header.php`.  BUT I couldn't figure out which one will dynamically keep referencing to those common folders and files no mater where the PHP page is.*

---

**UPDATE 1:** to have a clear view of what is happening, you can [download a snippet of the script from here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jygzy85ruj3dvh6/sitename.rar?dl=0)

Comment: If I remember correctly `common/stylesheets/default.css` looks for a folder named common in the current location which should be `/common/stylesheets/default.css` which goes to the root and gets the common folder

Comment: @Class when use `/common/stylesheets/defaults.css` the page doesn't link to `default.css` file, and when I view the page source, the link is `localhost/common/stylesheets/defaults.css` so as you can see the `sitename` is missing.  on the other hand, when use `common/stylesheets/default.css` it works and the page source shows the link as `localhost/sitename/common/stylesheets/default.css`

Comment: @Class it has php contents but I removed them since they are not relevant to the question and to keep the code clean and tidy

Comment: `defaults` !== `default` and you might need to add in the `sitename` in every url/link like `/sitename/common…`

Comment: @Class, `defaults` is a typo, sorry for that.  FYI, I've added a download link to a snippet of the script in the post.

Comment: @Danijel, would you please provide more information / explanation about the absolute URL-s

Answer (score 3):

It is usually a good idea to use fully qualified or absolute URLs to reference your assets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.sitenamecom/some/path/to/common/stylesheets/default.css">
```

Since there are many places where you need the proper URL base to reach the different files, you could define a constant having the web root:

```
define('WEB_ROOT', 'http://www.sitename.com');
```

Then you could define other constants to have access to the different parts of the system:

```
define('WEB_ASSETS', WEB_ROOT . '/common');
```

So for the style sheet link in your `header.php` it would be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo WEB_ASSETS; ?>/stylesheets/default.css">
```

To `include` files the principle is the same only that in this case you don't work with URLs but with file system's paths. There's not really a *dynamic* way of solving this, it all goes down to absolute paths.

The problem here is that the tree structure in your local development environment might (and surely won't) match that of your server. So in the configuration file, which is located in your application's root you could define:

```
define('APP_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
```

Then lets use the `admin/index.php` file as example:

```
include '../../../config.inc.php'; 
include APP_ROOT . '/sitename/common/html/header.php';
```

The tricky part here is including the configuration. Since, until you do that the `APP_ROOT` won't be available, relative paths are needed to reach it, and it isn't possible to escape this one; unless you can fully trust the preferred absolute form:

```
include '/some/path/to/config.inc.php';
```

Having that leading slash, as I said before, will be a problem if the application is tested in different environments because it is rarely the case that `some/path/to` is always the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is the usual issue with structures that aren't using index.php for centralization. Maybe you can try adding another include that defines your directories as pseudo-constant and prepending them to your asset urls.

Or you can parse the request url on how deep it is and automatically prepend the needed ../ levels to your assets urls. I've done this for one of my past projects.

I got to warn you though, it's better to solve the root of the issue (lack of centralization) than adding workarounds. It will surely come back to haunt you sooner than you think.

Comment: @SULTAN: sorry but i've no access with the code anymore. i'll try to recreate the nesting algorithm i did before and post it here. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is likely what you are looking for.

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/sitename/common/html/header.php");
```

This should work from any directory. If you want it to be a little more dynamic than typing out "sitename", you can do this:

```
<?php
$sitename = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/" . $sitename[1] . "/common/html/header.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to Change your `<link rel="stylesheet" href="common/stylesheets/default.css">` to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../common/stylesheets/default.css">`

Comment: change it in which page?

Comment: Using relative links is unwieldy with more than a few levels of subdirectories. A preceding slash in the 'href' attribute of the HTML <link> tag directs the browser to the document root, as given by the webserver instance.

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple modification in php.ini to include footer.php and header.php for each script

```
auto_append_file=ABSOLUTE_PATH/footer.php
auto_prepend_file=ABSOLUTE_PATH/header.php
```

restart your Apache if you are running under easyPhp, xampp,....
Warning : This configuration will be applied in all projects that are executed with the modified PHP

Comment: i am pretty sure :), can you make a try and let me know ?

Comment: yes, I've just test it in my xampp and I guess it is affecting all other website in the htdocs

Answer (score 0):

Try `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/common/stylesheets/default.css">`

Note the leading slash... This directs server to the document root.

I tried it and it works.

**My tree:**

```
/var/www/html/
    subdir/
        body.php
    layout/
        header.php
        footer.php
    css/
        style.css
```

**header.php**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Header.</p>
    <hr>
```

**body.php**

```
<?php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/layout/header.php');
echo "Body.<br>";
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/layout/footer.php');
?>
```

**footer.php**

```
  </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
body {
  color: red;
}
```

Viewing `http://localhost/subdir/body.php` in the browser, I get the expected result: "Header" and "Body" are colored red.

Comment: I've tried your steps in my site but unfortunately it didn't work!  when using the `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/layout/header.php');` I got the warnings: `Warning: include(C:/xampp/htdocs/common/html/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\sitename\index.php on line 1

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'C:/xampp/htdocs/common/html/header.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\sitename\index.php on line 1`

Comment: Hmmm... check the permissions? Should be 755.

Comment: Also make sure to change '/layout/header.php' to the actual location of the header file relative to your document root. That was just for my example using the directory structure described.

Comment: Ok, but permission of what? the sitename? ... also, I've updated the /layout/header.php to my doc root, and I got that error, and if you look in error you will see `C:/xampp/htdocs/common/html/header.php` so it is pointing to the correct header.php file except it is missing the `sitename` in the path

Answer (score 0):

I would store the document root of your website in some define:

```
define('DOCROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

Do this in a PHP file that you include everywhere, preferably in some bootstrap PHP file.

Then you need to prepend your paths with this in your include lines:

```
<?php include(DOCROOT . "/common/html/header.php"); ?>
```

Have you also looked at [`include_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried PHP's set_include_path ?

You can add numerous paths in one set_include_path separating them with a ' :'.
 set_include_path('/home/mysite/includes1:/home/mysite/includes2').
[PHP.net -> set_include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php)

Answer (score 0):

Even without moving to a full front controller (and MVC) setup (which would be good), you are going to save yourself a lot of headaches if you introduce a simple bootstrap-like file.

It's not going to be perfect with your current setup, as your files are including different parts of your system (ie header.php) in various places and sub folders.

Having header load the first output things - i.e. doctype, head and head links etc - is fine in your basic structure, but you have now run into constraints which you cannot work around without making your `header.php` messy, or including numerous other files before `header.php`.

In a more solid framework design, the html and doctype outputs are after a lot of other things have been initiated and loaded, to allow control over said html and doctype.

But to help in your case, just load the bootstrap before anything else is loaded/included.

### Bootstrap

The bootstrap will load shared resources, and common used data and paths (etc) throughout your application.
You can then add anything else in the bootstrap in the future, if you find a scenario.

A simple example of something in your bootstrap:
`bootstrap.php` (MUST reside in your root web folder for following constant to work)

```
// Define root folder
define ('FOLDER_ROOT', __DIR__);
```

Then throughout your app you can reference that constant (`FOLDER_ROOT`) to determine the root folder, and work through subfolders as required.

So, using your current setup:
`index.php` (I presume is in root folder)

```
include('bootstrap.php');
include(FOLDER_ROOT.'/common/html/header.php');
// Everything else
```

So then in your bootstrap you can set other things, such as define the default doctype or character encoding, setup error management.
Although you would usually set things like doctype after bootstrap, in a class, the router, some controller, or even a template.
But as you are using common file includes rather than using a more conventional framework design pattern, this way will at least save you some headaches now, and possibly further down the line.

So again in the `bootstrap.php`:

```
// Define root folder
define ('FOLDER_ROOT', __DIR__);
// Define CSS folder using root folder constant above
define ('FOLDER_CSS', FOLDER_ROOT.'/common/stylesheets/');
```

Then in `header.php`:

```
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.FOLDER_CSS.'default.css">';
```

### Sub Folders (ie /admin)

Now in sub folders, such as `/pages/admin/dashboard.php` etc, you don't have access to these constants, because you are loading your header files and other template like things all separately "across your application".
So it becomes a battle to set your root folder, plus you are now managing it all twice!

You could try loading the root bootstrap file within your admin folder.
So in `dashboard.php`, something like:

```
include('/bootstrap.php');
// OR (more likely)
include('../../bootstrap.php');
```

But this is becoming messy, calling bootstrap in different places, having to call it differently too.

It's not ideal, but it is do-able, in that if you get the bootstrap loaded within your admin area, then you have the root path setup in admin area and so managing other files from your admin files should be easier.

You could try using a new admin specific bootstrap file, eg in `/pages/admin/`, have `adminBootstrap.php`.
But then you're setting two different constants for root, and likely more constants to get to your common and css files and folders. It's easy setting your web root path in a file that is in the web root path, and can be tricky (sometimes) setting web root path from another folder.

### Stylesheets

You mentioned that using `/common/stylesheets/defaults.css` (with a preceding slash) doesn't work and causes the source code to show `localhost/common/stylesheets/defaults.css`.
This would possibly indicate you need to configure your DocumentRoot.

On Linux it's in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`, then either the `default` file, or if you configured your own virtual sites then go into each one.

What is your DocumentRoot set as?

Although if you get the bootstrap working within the admin area this problem might go away, using the constant `FOLDER_CSS`.

### Folder Structure

I also think you should tidy up your folders, as you seem to have separated things into illogical folder names (perhaps logical to you, but will it be when you learn more and come back to it in a year, or another dev tries to use it?).

E.G. I would not know what on earth the folder `html` is going to contain, as HTML is a protocol, and ultimately your application will serve HTML.

Have a little read into MVC. Don't go into depth as it's a lot of reading/learning, but if you grasp the basics, you can then tidy up your own structure to create your own logical separation of presentation from business a little more logically than it is now.

### Front Controller

If instead of using include files, you had a framework, which loads bootstrap and application wide configs, error management, other stuff, then when you come to load your HTML (your header, footer etc), they will have all this application (root folder constants etc) pre-loaded regardless of which sub folder you are trying to load web pages from.

However as you are doing it, you are instead including these things manually whenever you need them in different files, in sub folders.

While you are introducing a small presence of DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) by having the doctype, head, etc in include files and re-using them, you are still having to repeat yourself with those include files as you re-use them wherever you need them.

Also, what if you wanted to re-style admin differently to the main site? You'd have to include a different header file or a different stylesheet, or just put all code in the same stylesheet.

I'm waffling, but hopefully I'm being clear, and you can see why using header includes is only a small step in the right direction and for small sites. I'm sure you progressed naturally to using those include files from typing out the head/doctype etc in every file.

However now you are trying to break out into other directions, as with your admin area, you can see the constraints and including those same files is becoming harder to manage as your entire application grows.

So if you had a front controller type setup, within your `dashboard.php` you would have been able to simply used the constants set in the root bootstrap file, and any other sub folder which would be accessed after the core application is loaded.

EG (if using front controller like pattern)
`dashboard.php`:

```
include(FOLDER_ROOT.'/common/html/header.php');
```

I know I've bashed on about front controller already, but a few years back I was at the stage you are now, and moved from having all my files including the header.php, then the page content, then including footer.php, etc, and I instead started using a front controller.
It's really sooo much better!

It is a fair learning curve (with learning curves in all sorts of directions and methods, requirements, etc) and as such will leave it up to you if you want to go further into that.

I now have my own basic MVC front controller system, which I just simply plonk a new file for a new website page into the view/pages folder, and the page can be used immediately in the browser (the system does everything else).